# Posgresql is trying to insert into GENERATED ALWAYS column

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE project_sectors(
sector_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
sector_name varchar(256),
project_count int,
PRIMARY KEY (sector_id)
);
```

And I am trying to execute a query for many tables with some particular column name:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
t text;
BEGIN
    FOR t IN
        SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'project_name'
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'INSERT METADATA FOR: %', t;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO project_sectors VALUES ($1, 0)'
        USING t;

    end loop;
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Once I try to run the query I get:

> [42804] ERROR: column "sector_id" is of type integer but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at EXECUTE

When previously the EXECUTE statement was

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO megaproject_sectors VALUES (''%I'', 0)', t)
```

I would get the error

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "railway"

railway is the value of t.

Why is it trying to insert data into GENERATED ALWAYS column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it trying to insert data into GENERATED ALWAYS column?

Because you are not specifying the target columns in your INSERT statement, so Postgres uses them from left to right.

It is good coding practice to **always** specify the target columns. As your table name is hardcoded, the dynamic SQL is unnecessary as well:

```
INSERT INTO project_sectors (sector_name, sector_count) VALUES (t.table_name, 0)
```

---

Note that in other database products, specifying less values than the table has columns would result in an error. So in e.g. Oracle your statement would result in "ORA-00947: not enough values"

Comment: Hmm. I see. What if I have a very large (50+) number of columns, do I still should specify all column names?

Comment: Yes, you should always specify the target columns - with that many columns it's even more important.